# Calculate the total time of videos with addEventListener loadedmetadata and save this in a global variable for use this in a setinterval

Tags: jquery, loops, video, addeventlistener

The idea is build a Slider for Videos Without Libraries, only JQUERY.

i want calculate the total time of the all videos for set this in a setInterval

My HTML

> ```
>     <div class="slider1">
>             <video width="100%" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" preload="">
>             <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
>              </video>
>     </div>
>
>     <div class="slider2">
>             <video width="100%" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" preload="">
>             <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
>              </video>
>     </div>
>
>     <div class="slider3">
>             <video width="100%" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" preload="">
>             <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
>              </video>
>     </div>
>
>     <div class="slider4">
>             <video width="100%" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" preload="">
>             <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
>              </video>
>     </div>
>                                                                           </div>
> ```

MY JS CODE:

```
myslider = {

    totalTimeOfVideos : 0,

    Sliderinit:function(){

        myslider.playRotate();

        **---- HOW I CAN CAPTURE THE TOTAL TIME OF VIDEOS ? ---
        ---  I NEED WAIT FOR THE FINISH OF THE addEventListener loadedmetadata ---- ?** 

        setInterval(function(){ myslider.playRotate(); },  HERE_MY_TOTAL_TIME_OF_VIDEOS);


    },

    playRotate : function(){

        for(i=0; i< $("div[class*='slider']").length ; i++) {

            video = $("div[class*='slider']")[i].children[0];
            video.counter = i;
            video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(index) {

                console.log("The Video in position: "+this.counter+ " have a duration of:"+index.target.duration);

                **---- HOW I CAN CAPTURE THE TOTAL TIME OF VIDEOS  AND USE THIS IN A SETINTERVAL? ------**

                example :
                myslider.totalTimeOfVideos+=index.target.duration;

            });
        }

        **-- if i want print the  value of myslider.totalTimeOfVideos here --- -the value is  0 ----  i need wait for the result of addEventListener loadedmetadata ---- HOW ?**
        console.log(myslider.totalTimeOfVideos)

    }
}

    $(document).ready(function() {
        myslider.Sliderinit();

    });
```

**---- HOW I CAN CAPTURE THE TOTAL TIME OF VIDEOS ? ---

---  I NEED WAIT FOR THE FINISH OF THE addEventListener loadedmetadata ---- ?

---- HOW I CAN CAPTURE THE TOTAL TIME OF VIDEOS  AND USE THIS IN A SETINTERVAL? ------

-- if i want print the  value of myslider.totalTimeOfVideos here --- -the value is  0 ----

- - -i need wait for the result of addEventListener loadedmetadata ---- HOW ?**

Comment: It depends on how many videos, you are going to display... If you don't have those metadata and depends on Javascript to count it, the best way is to preload them and store those metadata in an array. What's the Setinterval for here ?

Comment: hi !  bilel, thank you for you response, the videos quantity is N (but MAX  7 videos). yes, i depends that javascript count it...   in this example all video duration is 10 second (but the every videos duration maybe variable.. ..  )....  the setinterval is 4 X 10 = 40 Second (40000 milisenconds)

Answer (score 0):

[UPADATED] Using promises, we can preload videos metadata and store them in an array. What I did here is using local storage to store the timing array and use it's final Sum later.
Otherwise we will get 0 because of Asynchronicity of metadata preloading that didn't finished yet !

This way, you can separate all this from your Slider Code and just use `totalTime=(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('durations'))).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);`
.

```
function Preload(){

var slides = document.querySelectorAll('video');    
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            var ready = 0;
            var videosDura = [];
            slides.forEach(function (v) {
                v.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
                    videosDura.push(Math.round(v.duration));
                    ready++;
                    localStorage.setItem("durations", JSON.stringify(videosDura));
                    if (ready === slides.length) {
                        $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');
                        resolve();

                    }
                });
            });
        }).then(function () {
        console.log((JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('durations'))).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));

        // Call any function dependant on this Variable

    });
}  


$(document).ready(function () {
Preload();
});
```

[image]
[image]

There is another approach to check videos using [videoObject.readyState](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_video_readystate.asp) property.

In [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bilelh/xnzsfqyj/) you can test the expected result.

For performance and optimization, thinking of bandwidth, page loading speed, compatibility and mobile devices... I suggest you read first this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/fast-playback-with-video-preload) while working on your actual project.

The best approach to use video metadata is to use an API for ajax calls or pre-store it on the server side first. Some meta generator projects on Github:

- NodeJs : [Video Meta Data Api](https://github.com/fcingolani/video-metadata-api) / [Video Parser](https://github.com/egg-/video-parser)
- pHp : [MediaFile](https://github.com/wapmorgan/MediaFile)
- Go : [Viddio](https://github.com/jsimnz/viddio)

Comment: Thank you @bilel ,   excelent response ! .  now, i go to make the test. i write in few hours

Comment: There was a bug in the old code, I made it work better using promises! You can check my updated answer and Fiddle. By the way, sometimes sthg get wrong with Fiddle during execution it works perfect on own host

Comment: Hi @bilel ,  thanks for the update, otherwise it worked for me as long as I used array to save the data.

Today I must finish the entire script and upload it to my github and so we evaluate whether it is worth using promise or loadmetada.

Thank you for your help and inform you of the progress made

Comment: ji @bilel , you can view a minimal approach in this link  https://jsfiddle.net/hdkcreative/q4fxLnut/9/   by the moment, only work in desktop by this is only a idea.    wait for your feedback . thank you !

Comment: That looks cool ! When I disabled the mute property, It sounds like another video starts prematurely only in the first seconds... so I enabled the autoplay property only in the first video of an array I added for preloading optimization, if that fits with your design present or any used (visual) preloader, I suggest you start with an array of video sources... I tried here to generate videos tags dynamically, this way videos won't be preloaded prematurely in the webpage before starting your slider. Unless you are expecting that :) Here is an example http://videox.myartsonline.com/slider.php

Comment: i integrate this script with a  dinamyc php code for generate videos tags dynamically, and work